# While trying to invoke 'createWorkbook' on factory org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory and arguments

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have tried so many solutions, but all of them aren't gonna work for me, therefore, I want to get some help from you guys, please.

Error Code:

```
PS C:\Users\Sonic\Desktop\excel_reader_v.1_beta3-0> cd 'c:\Users\Sonic\Desktop\excel_reader_v.1_beta3-0'; & 'C:\Users\Sonic\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.24.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Users\Sonic\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\bin\java' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' 
'-cp' 'C:\Users\Sonic\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_8ljdlon05x6nh0xy6agu8fwea.jar' 'excel_reader.ExcelReader2d' 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: While trying to invoke 'createWorkbook' on factory org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory and arguments [java.io.BufferedInputStream@452b3a41]
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:357)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:316)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:234)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:200)
        at excel_reader.ExcelReader2d.main(ExcelReader2d.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:326)
        ... 4 more
```

My code:

```
package excel_reader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ExcelReader2d {

    // methods void ExeScan()
    public  static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Sonic\\Desktop\\ExcelReadingProject\\ExcelWorkbook.xlsx";

        String toSearch = "coresystem";
        int searchColumn = 7; // column H
        List<Row> results = new ArrayList<Row>();

        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for (Row row : sheet) { // iterate over all rows in the sheet
            Cell cellInSearchColumn = row.getCell(searchColumn); // get the cell in seach column (H)
            if (cellInSearchColumn != null) { // if that cell is present
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cellInSearchColumn, formulaEvaluator); // get string cell value
                if (toSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue)) { // if cell value equals the searched value
                    results.add(row); // add that row to the results
                }
            }
        }

        // print the results
        System.out.println("Found results:");
        for (Row row : results) {
            int rowNumber = row.getRowNum()+1;
            System.out.print("Row " + rowNumber + ":\t");
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
               System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

What have I tried: Reinstalling `.jar` files, make sure that what's in the dependency file is right, checking my codes (no red lines).
*ps. I only have 4 months experiences on java, did not know how dependency injection works and how to properly add a dependency file (`.pom.xml`), the tutorial that I watched, he taught me to put a `pom.xml` file and find dependency code online (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi), currently using Windows 10, vscode. tkx.

Comment: Do not mix different `apache poi` versions. See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204. To use the current `apache poi 4.1.1` all dependencies needs to be of that version. So `poi` of version `4.1.1` and `poi-ooxml` of version `4.1.1`. Also do not have different versions in class path. So not `poi-ooxml` of version `4.1.1` and `poi-ooxml` of version `3.x` or any other different version the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to you pom.xml the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using 3.11 ooxml, 4.1.1 ooxml and 4.1.1poi, will it still work? Thanks

Comment: @FlashSonic526: No, it will not. Do not mix different `apache poi` versions. See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204.

Comment: @AxelRichter I see, thank you. It works now but I got new error XD Would you mind helping? Thanks.